# Rails + Mongoid + Carrierwave + Cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary, uploadcare

I'm migrating from Uploadcare to Cloudinary.

But when I try to update the file field, the field is setting with "*old*"

```
p = Photo _id: 556d225e69702d45b0000000, created_at: 2015-06-02 03:26:22 UTC, updated_at: 2015-06-02 03:26:22 UTC, file: nil
p.file = p.id
p.save
```

Returning

```
Photo _id: 556d225e69702d45b0000000, created_at: 2015-06-02 03:26:22 UTC, updated_at: 2015-07-30 19:41:12 UTC, file: "_old_"


p.file = <PhotoUploader:0x007fe96fc86800 @model=#<Photo _id: 556d225e69702d45b0000000, created_at: 2015-06-02 03:26:22 UTC, updated_at: 2015-07-30 19:41:12 UTC, file: "_old_">, @mounted_as=:file, @stored_public_id=nil, @stored_version=nil, @file=nil, @original_filename=nil, @public_id=nil, @storage=#<Cloudinary::CarrierWave::Storage:0x007fe9701f8f18 @uploader=#<PhotoUploader:0x007fe96fc86800 ...>>>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out the problem!

Carrierwave don't let you change the upload column If there is no image uploaded before.

So...you have to upload a sample image before

```
p = Photo.find(:id)
p.remote_file_url = "http:sample.com/image.png"
p.save
```

Then... change the your ***photo_uploader.rb*** to Cloudinary options

```
include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
```

And finally...

```
p.file = 'cloudinary public id'
p.save
```

And GOTCHA!

Answer (score 3):

If you save the model without assigning a value to the uploader field and then later assign a value, CarrierWave will temporarily [set the field](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave-mongoid/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/mongoid.rb#L39-L40) to `_old_` to force Mongoid to store the field. The correct value is assigned once the model is persisted:

```
001 > p = Photo.new title: 'Out with the old!'
 => #<Photo _id: 55c76e895d8b01bef0000000, title: "Out with the old!", image: nil, clean: nil>
002 > p.save
 => true
003 > p
 => #<Photo _id: 55c76e895d8b01bef0000000, title: "Out with the old!", image: nil, clean: nil>
004 > p.image = File.open( 'giraffe-small.jpg')
 => #<File:giraffe-small.jpg>
005 > p
 => #<Photo _id: 55c76e895d8b01bef0000000, title: "Out with the old!", image: "_old_", clean: nil>
006 > p.save
 => true
007 > p
 => #<Photo _id: 55c76e895d8b01bef0000000, title: "Out with the old!", image: "image/upload/v1439133413/dyirrctc3ls3ficre7hj.jpg", clean: nil>
```

Please note that the Cloudinary uploader accepts either an image identifier or a File object (see below).

**Model**

```
class Photo
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

**Uploader**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
end
```

#### Store a reference to an image already uploaded to your Cloudinary account

if your image URL is http://res.cloudinary.com/tocker/image/upload/v1435050504/sample.jpg*

```
p = Photo.new
p.title = "Existing image"
signature = Cloudinary::Utils.api_sign_request({:public_id=>"sample", :version=>"1435050504"}, Cloudinary.config.api_secret)
p.image = "image/upload/v1435050504/sample#{signature}"
p.save
```

*the image url can be found in your [Cloudinary media library](https://cloudinary.com/console/media_library).

#### Upload a local image file and store the reference

```
p = Photo.new
p.title = "Uploaded local image"
p.image = File.open( path_to_local_image_file)
p.save
```